# Unknown brick/piece information (curved, decorated slope)

Tags: part-identification

Recently, I got a huge box of LEGO sets all mixed together.
I have been slowly identifying the sets that are there.
Some are complete, while others not, but I have been managing so far.

Still, there is one piece that I failed to discover what it is.
I remember seeing it a while back but can't say from where.

Can someone help me out and tell me what brick this is?

[image: brick image]

Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It would be a [Slope, Curved 2 x 2 Lip, No Studs with Island Xtreme Stunts Logo and Flames Pattern](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogItem.asp?P=30602pb002).